# How to change tab width in terminal in Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: 10.04, command-line, tabs

When I press tab in terminal it goes very far. So I would like to change tab width, make it smaller. Anyone could help me, please?

Answer (score 42):

You can set the tab width on any terminal to 4 (for example) by using the following command:

```
tabs -4
```

You can also set an explicit tablist. Consider looking at the man page.

Comment: This breaks `scp` and `rsync` on Ubuntu 19, i.e., `scp myfile.txt user@ubuntu19:/tmp/`, if the `ubuntu19` has `tabs -4` on its `~/.bashrc` file. Instead, use `[[ $- == *i* ]] && tabs -4` on your `~/.bashrc` and this problem will be fixed because it will make the command only run on interactive shells: [Getting stty: standard input: Inappropriate ioctl for device when using scp through an ssh tunnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623021/getting-stty-standard-input-inappropriate-ioctl-for-device-when-using-scp-thro)

Comment: Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5):

If you are referring to using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in the terminal, I found this at UF.
[Ubuntu Forums Thread #7788701](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=7788701):

A possibility is setting the spacing in the application you are using via the terminal. For example in *vim* - `:set tabstop=4` .

Or you could look into the man page for the *expand* command with `man expand`. Example of usage - `expand -t 4 mytextfile.txt` - this would convert the tab spacing when viewing a file from the default 8 to 4.